# Python Replace an Undetermined length of Text

Tags: python, regex, replace, substitution

I have a string like this:

```
Hi. My name is _John_. I am _20_ years old.
```

and I'd like to convert it into this:

```
Hi. My name is <b>John</b>. I am <b>20</b> years old.
```

I did something like this but no luck.

```
import re
text = "Hi. My name is _John_. I am _20_ years old."
pattern = "(.*)(\_)(.*)(\_)(.*)"
re.sub(pattern, r'\1<b>\3</b>\5', text)
'Hi. My name is _John_. I am <b>20</b> years old.'
```

What is wrong with the pattern? Why is it not seeing the first bold text?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to:

```
pattern = "_([^_]*)_"
re.sub(pattern, r'<b>\1</b>', text)
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/HWDcY).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `*` is greedy and consumes as many characters as possible (including more `_`). To fix that, you can use the non-greedy alternative `*?` as follows:

```
>>> pattern = r'_(.*?)_'
>>> replacement = r'<b>\1</b>'
>>> re.sub(pattern ,replacement, text)
'Hi. My name is <b>John</b>. I am <b>20</b> years old.'
```

Note that `re.sub` behaves like `re.search` instead of `re.match`. That is, you can use a pattern that just partially matches the input (in this case, just some text surrounded by `_`) instead of something that matches the whole line.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your first `.*`in the pattern is eating everything to the left of the last possible match. It is therefore said that `*` is *greedy*. Use a *non-greedy pattern*

```
pattern='_(.+?)_'
re.sub(pattern, r'<b>\1</b>', text)
```

`?` makes the match *non-greedy*; as short as possible. + required at east one character between the two underscores in order for it to be replaced with `<b>text</b>`. So `__` will remain `__`

If you would like `__` to become `<b></b>` then use `.*?`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using [String Templates](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0292/) ? They were build for something like this. Simple String substitutions. Hell of a lot cleaner & elegant than using regexes...

```
import string

new_style = string.Template('Hi. My name is $name. I am $age years old.')
print new_style % {'name':'<b>John</b>', 'age':'<b>20</b>'} #produces what u want.
```

For more on string template examples check this [activeState link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/304004-how-to-use-stringtemplate-from-python-24/)

Answer (score 2):

It's because the pattern is *greedy* and the first `(.*)` matches the text from the beginning all the way to the third `_`:

```
>>> re.match(pattern, text).groups()
('Hi. My name is _John_. I am ', '_', '20', '_', ' years old.')
```

Here is a simplified, non-greedy version:

```
>>> re.sub('_(.+?)_', r'<b>\1</b>', text)
'Hi. My name is <b>John</b>. I am <b>20</b> years old.'
```

Comment: +1 if you are searching for things in the middle of the string (as with `.search` or `.sub` or `.findall`, there is no point in adding "anything before, and anything after" to the regex.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds remarkably like [markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), so if your goal is to parse that, there already exists a [python library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown).

Comment: more than markdown thingy. I feel this is closer to python string templates. check this - http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0292/